# Magento 2.3.2-p2 Payment Methods not showing in frontend

Tags: magento2.3

Im editing the magento 2 shop of a friend and after playing with the configuration of the shop to add FPT the payment methods are not shown anymore to the frontend user.

But I really did not change anything in the payment method section of the admin area.

I was also playing with the themes, but its defenitly not anything todo with the files. Because restoring the old theme files does not make a difference.

Restoring the old database via SQL on the other hand makes it work again. But I really dont want to work with the old DB because in the meantime I added like 250 products with images and attributes and we got some orders so it would cause confusion with the order numbers and so on...

Where in the DB or Admin Area outside of "Payment Options" could be some configurations that cause that error?

Inspecting the HTML created by knockout.js i found that the only difference is in the section:

`

```
<div class="payment-method-content">
    <div id="ppplus" style="height: 422px;"> <iframe id="iframe_0.39303568696323055" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" style="height: 422px; border: medium none; width: 765px;"></iframe></div>
    <!-- ko with: initPayPalPlusFrame() --><!-- /ko -->`
```

In the iframe is the only thing missing since the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated payment method Magento 2.3.3 delivery offers the two versions fundamental updates and changes in the stage, security, and installment techniques. Additionally, the new form is professed to incorporate in excess of 170 useful fixes to the center stage and improvements in the security. Because of the colossal local area, Magento endorsed and executed more than commitments to the most recent form. These commitments incorporate minor center code fixes and surprisingly huge enhancements in Inventory Management

Comment: so you say i should be updating.. lets give it a try thank you for your answer